# how to change color of text following function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, colors, radio-button

Ok before i make spaghetti of this code i thought id ask around here. ive made a quiz for an online site.

The answers are stored in an array, and ive a function that checks the answers array to what youve clicked. then it counts them and gives you your score.

but i want to change the clor of the right answer wen the user clicks the score button. so the correct answers are highlighted. something like this https://www.shutterpoint.com/Home-Quiz.cfm (just hit submit at the bottom, no need to do the quiz).

the little answer icon at the side looks flashy but id rather just have the text change color. heres how my questions are formatted

```
<p>Film speed refers to:</p>
<p id = "question1">
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="Wrong" value = "a" onClick = "recordAnswer(1,this.value)"/>How long it takes to develop film. <br/>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="Wrong" value = "b" onClick = "recordAnswer(1,this.value)"/>How fast film moves through film-transport system.  <br/>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="Answer" value = "c" onClick = "recordAnswer(1,this.value)"/>   How sensitive the film is to light.  <br/>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="Wrong" value = "d" onClick = "recordAnswer(1,this.value)"/>    None of these makes sense. <br/></p>
```

and these are the two functions that are called throughout. record answer is called every time the user clicks a button

```
 function recordAnswer(question,answer)
{
answers[question-1] = answer;
}
```

this is the final button which calculates the score

```
function scoreQuiz()
{
var totalCorrect = 0;
for(var count = 0; count<correctAnswers.length;count++)
{
    if(answers[count]== correctAnswers[count])

    totalCorrect++;

}
<!--
alert("You scored " + totalCorrect + " out of 12 correct!");
-->
}
```

another function is best i think.  ive already made attempts at it and know i have to set the color using

```
document.getElementById('Answer').style.color = '#0000ff';
```

onyl problem is 'Answer' doesnt seem to be registering. anyone shed some light?

---

ok so i cant have two or more of the same ids.

what about

```
if(value == correctAnswers[])
{
// change the color.
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to have two or more elements with the same `id`.

Comment: damn. wasnt aware of that. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**QUICK RESPONCE:**

USE **`<P>`**

```
    <p>
    <input type="radio" name="question_1" class="wrong" value="a" />
    How long it takes to develop film. 
  </p>
```

THEN

```
if(value == correctAnswers[])
{
YOUR_ELEMENT.parentNode.style.color = 'green';
}
```

**IMPROVEMENT**

**DEMO**: http://jsbin.com/aceze/26

hi Overtone!

first of all you need to restyle a litte your HTML schema!

you have multiple `id="Wrong"` instead of `class="Wrong"`

then here how your code should look:

```
var answers = { 1:'a' , 2:'f' , 3:'h' };

    function checkQuestions() {
    var form_elements = document.question_form.elements.length;

    for ( var i = 0; i < form_elements; i++ )
    {
        var type = question_form.elements[i].type;
        if ( type == "radio" ){
        var quest = question_form.elements[i];
        //if ( quest.checked ) {
        var question_index = parseInt(quest.name.split('_')[1]);
        //}
        if ( quest.value == answers[question_index] ) {
        quest.parentNode.style.border = '1px solid green';
        quest.parentNode.style.color = 'green';
          } else {
        //quest.parentNode.style.border = '1px solid red';
        quest.parentNode.style.color = 'red';
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

USE a **FORM** and one time **SUBMIT BUTTON** instead of adding `onclick` to each **RADIO** like this

```
 <form name="question_form" id="question_form" method="POST" action='#'>
      <div id="question_1"> <H4>QUESTIONS TIME 1</H4>
      </div>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="question_1" class="wrong" value="a" />
        How long it takes to develop film.
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="question_1" class="wrong" value="b" />
        How fast film moves through film-transport system.
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="question_1" class="answer" value="c" />
        How sensitive the film is to light.
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="question_1" class="wrong" value="d" />
        None of these makes sense. 
      </p>

       ...
       ...

        <input type="radio" name="question_2" class="wrong" value="h" />
        <span>None of these makes sense. 
        </span>
      </p>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="checkQuestions();return false;" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

PS: demo example updated with style... for sake!

Answer (score 0):

You should format your `id`s in a more usable way.. I'd suggest something similar to `questionNUMBER_answerVALUE`.

Then it'd be a simple matter of...

```
for (var i=0; i<correctAnswers;i++) {
  document.getElementById("question" + (i+1) + "_answer" + correctAnswers[i].toUpperCase()).style.color = "#0000FF";
};
```

Just check I've got your zero/non-zero indexing correct with regard to question/ answer numbers.

Comment: new versions up. id has been changed to those with being correct and thos that are wrong. any idea how id change the color using your for loop? i can kinda see what your doing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `<p>` I would consider using a `<label for='question1_answerA'>How long it takes to develop film.</label>`. You can still use a jQuery selector to find it and it feels more semantically correct. You will then also be able to select the option by clicking the text.

Although your other HTML isn't semantically correct. You need to give each radio a unique ID.

Answer (score -1):

Obligatory jquery solution:

```
var highlightCorrect = function(){
    $(".Answer").css("color", "#00FF00");
}
```

This is all assuming that you fix your HTML to use classes rather than IDs for "Wrong" and "Answer".